# Html/ javascript form calculation issues

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, math

I'm new to coding for websites and am really struggling! I'm trying to add the select values from different select menu options to a total which will then give me a figure I can add to a number entered in a free text box.

I"ve searched extensively on the net and on this site and have found examples that are similar but when I've tried them out it doesn't work with my additions/changes!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!! Below is my html and also javascript.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>


</head>

<form action="" id="myform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="cont_order">

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="selectmenu" class="select">
            <div align="right"></div>
          </label>
          <div align="center"></div>
    </div>
        <div align="center">
          </p>


          <select name="Sport" id="Sport" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="a" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="0">Sport</option>
            <option value="Tennis">Tennis</option>
            <option value="Golf">Golf</option>
            <option value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
            <option value="Rugby">Rugby</option>
            <option value="Polo">Polo</option>
            <option value="Fencing">Fencing</option>
            <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
          </select>

          <br/>


          <label for="selectmenu" class="select">
            <div align="right"></div>
          </label>
          <div align="center"></div>
    </div>
        <div align="center">
          </p>


          <select name="Star Sign" id="SS" data-native-menu="false" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="0">Star Sign</option>
            <option value="1.5">Aries</option>
            <option value="3">Taurus</option>
            <option value="1.5">Gemini</option>
            <option value="2">Cancer</option>
            <option value="3">Leo</option>
            <option value="1.5">Virgo</option>
            <option value="2">Libra</option>
            <option value="3">Scorpio</option>
            <option value="2">Sagittarius</option>
            <option value="1.5">Capricorn</option>
            <option value="0.5">Aquarius</option>
            <option value="0.5">Pisces</option>
          </select>

<br/>


          <label for="selectmenu" class="select">
            <div align="right"></div>
          </label>
          <div align="center"></div>
    </div>
        <div align="center">
          </p>

          <br/>

          <select name="Hobby" id="Hobby" data-native-menu="false" onchange="calculateTotal()">Hobby
            <option value="0">Hobby</option>
            <option value="A lot">A lot</option>
            <option value="Some">Some</option>
            <option value="Few">Few</option>
            <option value="None">None</option
          </select> 
    </div>

    <br/>

          <label for="selectmenu" class="select">
            <div align="right"></div>
          </label>
          <div align="center"></div>
      </div>
        <div align="center">
          </p>

          <br/>


          <select name="Favourite Colour" id="FC" data-native-menu="false" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="0">Favourite Colour</option>
            <option value="1.5">Black</option>
            <option value="3">Blue</option>
            <option value="1.5">Brown</option>
            <option value="2">Green</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="1.5">Pink</option>
            <option value="2">Purple</option>
            <option value="3">Red</option>
            <option value="2">Yellow</option>
            <option value="1.5">White</option>
            <option value="4">Other</option>

          </select>

          <br/>

        <p>&nbsp;     

 <br/>



    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="Age">
            <div align="center">Age
              :
            </div>
          </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" value=""  />
          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <p>&nbsp;<a href="#" data-role="button">    <input type='submit' id='Submit' value='submit' onclick="calculateTotal()"/>

        <br/>
        </div>

        </form>




</div>


</body>
</html>



// JavaScript Document

var Sport = new Array();
Sport["Tennis"]=1.5;
Sport["Golf"]=3;
Sport["Soccer"]=2;
Sport["Rugby"]=3;
Sport["Polo"]=1.5;
Sport["Fencing"]=2;
Sport["Swimming"]=3; 

var SS = new Arr4ay();
Star_Sign["Aries"]=1.5;
Star_Sign["Taurus"]=3;
Star_Sign["Cancer"]=2;
Star_Sign["Leo"]=3;
Star_Sign["Virgo"]=1.5;
Star_Sign["Libra"]=2;
Star_Sign["Scorpio"]=3;
Star_Sign["Sagittarius"]=2;
Star_Sign["Capricorn"]=1.5;
Star_Sign["Aquarius"]=0.5;
Star_Sign["Pisces"]=1.5;

var Hobby = new Array();
Hobby["A lot"]=0.5;
Hobby["Some"]=1;
Hobby["Few"]=1;
Hobby["None"]=2;


var FC = new Array();
Favourite_Colour["Blue"]=3;
Favourite_Colour["Brown"]=1.5;
Favourite_Colour["Green"]=2;
Favourite_Colour["Orange"]=3;
Favourite_Colour["Pink"]=1.5;
Favourite_Colour["Purple"]=2;
Favourite_Colour["Red"]=3;
Favourite_Colour["Yellow"]=2;
Favourite_Colour["White"]=1.5;
Favourite_Colour["Other"]=4;


function calc() {
    var Sport = Number(document.getElementsById("Sport").value);
    var SS = Number(document.getElementsById("SS").value);
    var Hobby = Number(document.getElementsById("Hobby").value);
    var FC = Number(document.getElementsById("FC").value);
    var Age = Number(document.getElementsById("Age").value);

    var total = Sport + SS + Hobby + FC;

    var Score = Age = Score


}// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: Finding and using the error console in your browser which will give you some idea of where errors are occurring. Occurs in different areas of menu in different browsers. Look for 'developer' in the menus.

Answer (score 0):

In your function calc replace Number with either parseInt if you always expect an integer from your value or parseFloat otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you're after you could just use the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

`Array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});`

So for you:

```
function calc() {
new tempAry = [
  Number(parseInt (document.getElementsById("Sport").value),10),
  Number(parseInt (document.getElementsById("SS").value),10),
  Number(parseInt (document.getElementsById("Hobby").value),10),
  Number(parseInt (document.getElementsById("FC").value),10)
];


var total = tempAry.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
    return previousValue + currentValue;
});

//No idea what these are for
//var Age = Number(document.getElementsById("Age").value);
//var Score = Age = Score
}
```

Not sure exactly what you're after, nor what `Score is meant for, but total should equal the total number.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it didn't seem to do anything. SHould I be assigning a document.write or alert? I would like it to publish the result on a new browser page. Sorry if I'm not making much sense!